# social django package for facebook signin shows url error

Tags: django

When am using social django package for facebook signin but it shows error as :

```
 Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's 
 domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains 
 of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.
```

In the fb app urlredirect provided is https://localhost:8000 .

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to **Facebook developer** page and login

2.Then select your app

3.Go to settings > basics

4.Add App Domains localhost

5.And add Website https://localhost:8000/